# How do a add a directory to my path in Ubuntu for my personal account

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path

I've read that I'm supposed to add in the .profile but this file resides in etc, which is off the root. Now, I'm part of a large cluster so I doubt I will have permissions to this file.

Is there an equivalent to this file existing some where in my home (like bash_profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally on Ubuntu `${HOME}/.profile` sources `${HOME}/.bashrc`

Example from my stock `${HOME}/.profile`:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

`${HOME}/.profile` is sourced on session login.

There is a thing that you might want to be aware of though.  To my knowledge, the `${HOME}/.bashrc` is also sourced on each login shell.

This quirk will cause `${HOME}/.bashrc` to be sources twice; Once on session login and once on the login shell (starting a terminal).

But I can't help wondering: if your `.profile` is located in `/etc` is you `${HOME}` also `/etc/`? That would cause problems since you do not have write permissions there, and everything is relative to `${HOME}`

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

From `/etc/skel/.profile:`

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.
```

So, if using bash put a `.bash_profile` in your `${HOME}` effectively overriding your `.profile`.

Anyways, it all depends on what is going on in your `/etc/.profile`.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks you. I just needed to add to the bashrc. I'm new to Linux.